# Comments Listview in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have an Activity which contains different items, one of those item is ListView.
I created a custom list adapter and sending to it a json array.
The data for the list arrives from the server.

The list purpose is to make comments list. I allowed the user to insert
a comment and then I show it in the ListView.
When I have some items in the list it works, and the items are shown.
The problem is when listview is empty and the user post a comment.
I see that that data is changed but I don't see the item, means the list is not refreshed..

So I tried to add to the listview an empty view but it doesn't work.

Here is an updated code: (**UPDATE**)

```
       if (!s.isEmpty() && !s.equals("{}")) {

            try {
                if (commentsListAdapter == null) {
                    commentsList.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.dummy));
                    commentsListAdapter = new CommentsListAdapter(PostView.this);
                }
                JSONObject resObj = new JSONObject(s);
                list.add(resObj);

                commentsListAdapter.setDataSet(list);

                cmntTxt.setText("");
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

                commentCounter.setText(Integer.toString(list.size()));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And inside the Adapter I have this function:

```
public void setDataSet(List<JSONObject> list){
    commentsList = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

But the problem is not fixed..

Comment: Where is the code for listview.setAdapter()? Perhaps post more code in this method or Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice the code `list.add(resObj)` appears after `new CommentsListAdapter` when the list is empty and appears before `new CommentsListAdapter` when the list is NOT empty.

I suspect the Adapter `CommentsListAdapter` is not using the object `list` for the data storage. In that case, you need to make a public method in the adapter to make updates. Another words, the adapter is using another object for data storage.

It may help to post the code for CommentsListAdapter also. But I hope I am correct about my statements.
I hope that is clear...

Comment: Hi thanks, I updated my code but I get the same result as the previous code

Comment: @Elior, This problem should not be hard to fix. Post the Adapter code.

Comment: Thanks :) I looked in other code of mine and didn't notice I forgot to set the adaper for the listview . Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please change the following code:

```
public void setDataSet(List<JSONObject> list){
    commentsList = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

to :

```
private List<JSONObject> commentsList = new ArrayList<>();

public void setDataSet(List<JSONObject> list){
    commentsList.clear();
    commentsList.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And use `commentsList` for all other methods in your adapter. This is a better way for notifyDataSetChanged() to work.

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding your comment from the outside i.e from activity and not from adapter than whenever you set the adapter do this.

youradapterobject.notifyDataSetChanged();

and dont do commentsListAdapter == null than setemptyview

it automatically sets the emptyview if its null

correct usage
 list.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.erromsg));